# deleting key from AVL tree that points to 1 or more values

Tags: c++

I am working on a uni project and i need to create a idea bank that stores an idea.
Per requirements i have created an inverted index algorithm that takes all words from one idea and stores them into an AVL tree, when retrieving a word from my tree it returns the ID the word was found in.

the problem i am having is when i am deleting an idea and thus need to delete the words contained in that ID from my tree. the problem is that, whenever one word is found in two or more ideas it removes the word from all ideas.

for example
the word "Technology" can be found in idea 1 and 2
so when i traverse my tree my output would be

Key: Technology 
ID: 1,2

but when i am deleting idea 1, instead of my output showing

Key Technology
ID: 2

it just shows no Ideas for that word.

here is the relevant code:

```
class Idea{
private:
int ID;
string content;
vector<string> keyword;
public:
int getID() {return ID;}
string getContent(){return content;}
vector<string> getKeyword(){return keyword;}

};
class IdeaBank{
private:
vector<idea>newIdea;
public:
void deleteID(int ID);
};

struct Index {
    string key;
    vector<int> idList;
};

void IdeaBank::deleteIdea(int ID)
{
    vector<string> wordsToDelete;
    vector<string>keywordsToDelete;
    Index index;
    bool del=false;
    for (int i = 0; i < newIdea.size(); i++) {
        if (ID == newIdea[i].getID()) {
            keywordsToDelete = newIdea[i].getKeyword();
            Idea idea;
            string str = newIdea[i].getContent();
            char delim = ' ';
            idea.splitKeywordsFromTxt(str, wordsToDelete, delim);
            newIdea.erase(newIdea.begin() + i);
            del = true;
        }
    }



    for (int i=0;i<keywordsToDelete.size();i++)
    {
        if (tree.AVL_Retrieve(keywordsToDelete[i],index))
        {
            for (int j=0;j<index.idList.size();j++)
            {
                if (ID == index.idList[j])
                {
                    tree.AVL_Delete(keywordsToDelete[i]);
                    del = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsToDelete.size(); i++) {
        if (tree.AVL_Retrieve(wordsToDelete[i],index))
        {
            for (int j=0;j<index.idList.size();j++)
            {
                if ( ID == index.idList[j])
                {
                    tree.AVL_Delete(wordsToDelete[i]);
                    del = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    if (!del)
    cout << "Could not delete idea "<< ID<<endl;
    else
    cout << "successfully deleted idea for ID "<<ID<<endl;
}
```

the above function, stores every word from the selected idea into a vector and then i retrieve each word from my tree to be deleted.

My question:
when deleting a word from my tree that may return more than 1 ID, how can i only remove the ID from the ID to be deleted only.
a better example of input an output:

Idea 1:

keywords: dog

contents: i like dogs

idea 2:

keywords: dog

contents: animals

when traversing my tree my output would be

key:dog
ID: 1,2

key: i
ID:1

Key: like
ID: 1

Key: dogs
ID: 1

Key: Animals
ID: 2

when deleting ID 1
my expected output should be:
key:dog
ID: 2

Key: Animals
ID: 2

instead i get

Key: Animals
ID: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is right here:

```
        for (int j=0;j<index.idList.size();j++)
        {
            if ( ID == index.idList[j])
            {
                tree.AVL_Delete(wordsToDelete[i]);
                del = true;
            }
        }
```

At that point you've found the idea inside the list of ideas that have that keyword.

The problem with this code is that deletes the word from the tree as soon as it find that it contains the idea ID instead of **just removing that ID from the vector**. The word must be removed **only when there are no more references to it** (i.e. when `idList` is empty). Something like this:

```
        for (int j=0;j<index.idList.size();j++)
        {
            if (ID == index.idList[j])
            {
                index.idList.erase(index.idList.begin() + j);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index.idList.empty())
        {
            tree.AVL_Delete(wordsToDelete[i]);
            del = true;
        }
```

**Update:** added `break` statement

Comment: i appreciate your answer, unfortunately this did not work as it produced the same outcome for me. but i understand what you mean

Comment: actually it seems like this code will skip over the word if it has more than one ID related to it

Comment: for example if the retrieved word is found in ID 1 and 2, and i am trying to delete ID 1 then the word will never be deleted because idList will never be empty, it will contain the ID 2 in there

Comment: Of course this code skips the word if it has more than one ID related, that's the whole point! You don't want to delete words that are in use, do you? In your example: shouldn't the word be deleted only after ID2 is deleted? The main idea is that you should add reference counting to your keywords. Each idea adds 1 to each keyword it contains and, when deleting an idea, the reference should be decreased. The word can be deleted only when count reaches zero.

Comment: btw, did you modify both for loops? because both keywords and words should have the check